# Alter Table and Input Values?

Tags: oracle, alter

The question is:

> "5.   Calculate and display the total amount each college spends on professor salaries, the lowest salary and highest salary for each college. Name these columns “Total Budget”, “Lowest Salary”, and “Highest Salary”. Only include colleges where the average salary budget is greater than $80,000.  Order the results alphabetically by college name. You will use the professor table for this query."

```
ALTER TABLE professor
ADD ('Total Budget' varchar(10),
'Lowest Salary' varchar(6),
'Highest Salary' varchar(7))

INSERT INTO professor (Total Budget)
SELECT SUM(pr_salary) FROM professor
WHERE professor.pr_salary > 80000 AND professor.pr_title='Professor'

INSERT INTO professor (Lowest Salary)
SELECT MIN(pr_salary) FROM professor
WHERE professor.pr_salary > 80000 AND professor.pr_title='Professor'

INSERT INTO professor (Highest Salary)
SELECT MAX(pr_salary) FROM professor
WHERE professor.pr_salary > 80000 AND professor.pr_title='Professor';
```

-- I'm not sure how the syntax works, but this is what I wrote, yet it says:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I'm using Oracle.

Comment: missing `;` is that?

Comment: Even if I add a ; at the end of every query, it still gives the same error

Comment: The datatype is varchar but you are selecting numbers. Can you change them?

Comment: What is the alternative command if the values are numbers?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE professor ADD (Total_Budget number,
Lowest_Salary number,
Highest_Salary number);` Then your inserts

Comment: Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things which you should always consider while coding. First of all plz VARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR data type. Also please dont use ' for column nomenclature. " are used when we need to use space in the column nomenclature or to make column name case sensitive or need to use oracle RESERVED KEYWORDS as a column name for example "Column 1" is not equal to "COLUMN 1". But as a good coding practice avoid using such nomenclature. I have modified syntactically your code hope it helps.

```
ALTER TABLE professor
ADD 
("Total Budget" varchar2(10),
"Lowest Salary" varchar2(6),
"Highest Salary" varchar2(7)
);

INSERT INTO professor ("Total Budget")
SELECT SUM(pr_salary) FROM professor
WHERE professor.pr_salary > 80000 AND professor.pr_title='Professor';

INSERT INTO professor ("Lowest Salary")
SELECT MIN(pr_salary) FROM professor
WHERE professor.pr_salary > 80000 AND professor.pr_title='Professor';

INSERT INTO professor ("Highest Salary")
SELECT MAX(pr_salary) FROM professor
WHERE professor.pr_salary > 80000 AND professor.pr_title='Professor';
```